# Anime in which a boy shows up from a girl's dream and says that his world is falling apart and that they need to work together

Tags: story-identification, anime

In this anime, a girl dreams about another world. One day, a boy from the other world came into her room and asked for help because his world was falling apart. He's like some sort of royal in his world. All I remember is that they had to work together to fight. Also, the world is on top of their world.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made? Also, was it a movie or a series?

Comment: I watched in 2020 it was made in the 2000's

Comment: If anyone posts a correct answer, please consider marking it as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

Answer (score 6):

Is this ***[Munto](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1356921/)*** (2003)...?

From [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/anime/1174/Munto):

> **Above Earth, invisible to humans, float the Heavens—a collection of floating island kingdoms supported by the magic of their godlike inhabitants.** The mysterious power source known as Akuto enables this magic to exist, but this is quickly running out. In response to this energy crisis, most of the kingdoms in the Heavens agree to use the minimum amount of Akuto required to sustain themselves, except for the Magical Kingdom. **The leader of this kingdom, the Magical King Munto, believes that Akuto can be replenished if he travels to Earth and meets a mysterious girl shown to him by a seer.** While Munto sets off on the dangerous journey, the other kingdoms attempt to destroy the Magical Kingdom and acquire the remaining Akuto for themselves.
>
> **On Earth, Yumemi Hidaka is dealing with her own problems. She can see floating islands in the sky that nobody else can.** While her best friend Ichiko Ono believes her, Yumemi wonders if she is going insane. **When Munto suddenly appears before her, Yumemi dismisses him as a mere delusion.** She is more concerned about her 13-year-old friend Suzume Imamura, who is attempting to elope with her delinquent boyfriend. **As the Magical Kingdom nears the point where it will fall from the sky, Munto's quest to save both the Heavens and Earth grows increasingly desperate.**

The plot summary above is for the two-part original video animation (OVA), which was released in 2003. The story was also adapted into a TV series -- titled *[Sora wo Miageru Shoujo no Hitomi ni Utsuru Sekai](https://myanimelist.net/anime/5702/Sora_wo_Miageru_Shoujo_no_Hitomi_ni_Utsuru_Sekai)* or *Munto TV* -- released in 2009.

> To save both the Magical Kingdom and the Heavens and restore the flow of akuto, the flow of energy of everything, the Magical King Munto must follow a vision and find the girl Yumemi in the normal world. **Yumemi herself is just a normal girl except that she is the only one who can see the islands of the Heavens floating above. When Munto appears before her she starts thinking about hers and others responsibility to the world.**

Answer (score 2):

Is this [Vision of Escaflowne](https://myanimelist.net/anime/182/tenkuu_no_escaflowne)?

> Hitomi Kanzaki is just an ordinary 15-year-old schoolgirl with an interest in tarot cards and fortune telling, but one night, **a boy named Van Fanel suddenly appears from the sky along with a vicious dragon**. Thanks to a premonition from Hitomi, Van successfully kills the dragon, but a pillar of light appears and envelopes them both. As a result, **Hitomi finds herself transported to the world of Gaea, a mysterious land where the Earth hangs in the sky**.
>
> In this new land, Hitomi soon discovers that **Van is a prince of the Kingdom of Fanelia**, which soon falls under attack by the evil empire of Zaibach. In an attempt to fight them off, Van boards his family's ancient guymelef Escaflowne—a mechanized battle suit—but fails to defeat them, and Fanelia ends up destroyed. Now on the run, Hitomi and Van encounter a handsome Asturian knight named Allen Schezar, whom Hitomi is shocked to find looks exactly like her crush from Earth. With some new allies on their side, Van and Hitomi fight back against the forces of Zaibach as the empire strives to revive an ancient power.

The prince doesn't show up in her bedroom, but the rest might fit. In particular, I remember that she has dreams of Gaea before the prince shows up.